# Warning: Incorrect Integer Value error MYSQL

Tags: python, mysql

I am attempting to load csv files into a table in a database using python.

```
csv_data = csv.reader(file('ppi.csv'))

for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ADKnowledgeBase.PPI(a,b) VALUES("row[0]","row[1]");')
```

Whenever I run this, I get a warning stating `Incorrect Integer Value` and inserts 0's into my table.

When I `print row` I get [int0,int1] and they are ints so it's pushing in the ints and not null values.

I've attempted to remove the quotes around `"row[0]"` and `"row[1]` and instead use `VALUES(row[0],row[1]);` but that just gives me a syntax error. I've also attempted using `"%d"` and `%d`

My table was made using:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ADKnowledgeBase.PPI(a int, b int);
```

Comment: `"row[0]"` is not any integer I've heard of. (Hint: Use placeholder values)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variables in SQL statement in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902408/how-to-use-variables-in-sql-statement-in-python)

Comment: @tadman I tried using %s and %d but i encounter the same issue

Comment: @mcv Yes `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO ADKnowledgeBase.PPI(a,b) VALUES("%d","%d");',(row[0],row[1]))` and my error is something like `Warning: Incorrect integer value: ''19217'' for column 'a' at row 1` I have also tried changing the datatype to a varchar in my table and instead of %d to do %s and I still have the issue

Comment: @mcv yes it does at the end before the `cursor.close`

Comment: @mcv with just %d I get a mysql syntax error

Answer (score 1):

So [python mysql format query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html) string always uses `%s`

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO ADKnowledgeBase.PPI(a,b) VALUES(%s,%s)", (row[0],row[1]))
```